# Problemas con un ECHO en While

Tags: php

Esta vez le escribo porque tengo un problema que en cierta forma parecería sencillo y es con la muestra de un ECHO ya que tengo el siguiente código PHP que me muestra los resultados en una tabla, la cual funciona muy bien, pero cuando trato de hacer un ELSE para que me muestra el mensaje de "No hay Datos", en caso de no consiga ninguna información en la BD, me muestra el siguiente error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE), expecting end of file in C:XXXXXXXXX on line 15 (la linea 15 es donde esta ELSE)

Ya he tratado de con varias combinaciones como ELSE IF pero no funciona espero me puedan orientar.

Gracias a todos por su ayuda...

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
              <tr>
                <th class="center">#</th>
                <th class="center">Cedula</th>
                <th class="center">Nombres</th>
                <th class="center">Genero</th>
              </tr>
            
            <?php  
            $no = 1;
            $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT cedula_vecino,nombres_vecibo,genero_vecino FROM comunidad_vecino WHERE cedula_inmueble='$_GET[id]'ORDER BY cedula_vecino DESC");
            while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
           
              echo "<tr>
                      <td width='10' class='center'>$no</td>
                      <td width='10' class='center'>$data[cedula_vecino]</td>
                      <td width='60' class='left'>$data[nombres_vecino]</td>
                      <td width='10' class='center'>$data[genero_vecino]</td>
                    </tr>";
              $no++;
              
              }else{
              echo 'No hay Datos';
            }
              ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`else` viene de la sentencia `if`, no existe para `while`, por lo tanto deberás hacer una comprobación para ver si existen datos o no y de ser así  ahi debe ir el ciclo. Te dejo como debes hacerlo

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT ...");
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) {
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
              echo "<tr>
                      <td width='10' class='center'>$no</td>
                      <td width='10' class='center'>$data['cedula_vecino']</td>
                      <td width='60' class='left'>$data['nombres_vecino']</td>
                      <td width='10' class='center'>$data['genero_vecino']</td>
                    </tr>";
              $no++;
} else {
    echo 'No hay Datos';
}
```

Ahora bien, revisa tambien los indices de la variable $data, ya que debe ser una variable, un entero o un string.